# Trigger function when scrollbar touches a DIV bottom - jQuery

Tags: jquery, scrollbar, scrollto

I have a div that is in the middle of the page, I need to trigger a function when the scrollbar gets 100px before the bottom of a DIV.

I'm using jQuery.[image]

I played with all the combinations using

```
$(window).scrollTop();
$(document).height()
$('div').height();
```

but I can't get there.

Thanks for any help.

Comment: `if($(window).scrollTop() >= ($('div').offset().top + $('div').height() -100));`

Comment: the function is never triggered

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use this. Works in [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/xpzkooqm/)

```
$(window).scroll(function() {
   var divTop = $('#yourDivId').offset().top,
       divHeight = $('#yourDivId').outerHeight(),
       wHeight = $(window).height(),
       windowScrTp = $(this).scrollTop();
   if (windowScrTp > (divTop+divHeight-wHeight-100)){
        alert('reached');
   }
});
```

Comment: thanks for the answer but I've just tried and using your way, the function is triggered as soon as the "div top side" touches the window top side. I need that the function is triggered when the "div bottom side" - 100px  touches the window top side.

Comment: the function is not triggered at all now

Comment: @rolfo85 I have updated again and this time works in jsfiddle

Answer (score 0):

simple

```js
function onEndedScrollbar(element, range = 50/* < 50 px fire */) {
    $(element).scroll(function (e) {
        let d = (e.target.scrollHeight) - (e.target.scrollTop + e.target.offsetHeight);
        if (d < 50) {
            /* do somthing */
        }
    });
}
```